# Google Sheets Query() - How do I conditionally transform text in a column so it maps to a different (pretty) value?

Tags: google-sheets

I have some raw data that I am querying and want to represent it so it is human readable.

The raw data has raw labels so I am trying to rewrite the labels in my query to pretty labels

My source data looks like `A2:C`, and I have tables that map the raw titles to pretty titles `E2:F` and `H2:I`:

[image]

And I want to produce a table that has the raw titles mapped to pretty titles like this:

[image]

Example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FHICiv5GMScy5iRgZQaw5nf3NRH1x022XaqCqoAzIE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAP()` function like-

```
=MAP(A2:B5,LAMBDA(x,SUBSTITUTE(x,"_name_"," ")))
```

[image]

Comment: Updated my original post with my results. Is it possible to automatically look these values up from a table rather than manually mapping them? Also how can multiple values be changed? Do you have to nest `MAP` calls?

Answer (score 0):

Given your source table in A1:B5, your raw titles in D2:D3 and your pretty titles in E2:E3, you can try the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(
source_tbl,A1:B5,
raw_title,D2:D3,
pretty_title,E2:E3,
xlookup(source_tbl,raw_title,pretty_title,source_tbl)))
```

The XLOOKUP checks every cell of source_tbl array (hence the initial ARRAYFORMULA) for matches to the raw_title list, and where a match is found gives you the corresponding pretty_title. Where no match is found, the optional fourth argument of XLOOKUP ('missing values') allows for the substitution of the default #N/A value with another value, so by pointing XLOOKUP back at source_tbl it simply will give the original value in that cell.

**EDIT**
Based on updated requirements:

```
=arrayformula(let(
source_tbl,A2:C7,
raw_title,{E3:E7;H3:H4},
pretty_title,{F3:F7;I3:I4},
xlookup(source_tbl,raw_title,pretty_title,source_tbl)))
```

As your raw_titles and pretty_titles are spread over two tables, I've just concatenated them so that only a single XLOOKUP is still required.

Comment: I tried to use `XLOOKUP` however I was unable to get the desired result. I added an example sheet if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Comment: I've added an updated answer based on the example you've given in your 'source' tab. The principles are exactly the same as the original answer.